# Git add error - unknown switch

Tags: git, github

I just did `git init` inside of my existing project directory and I wanted to add all of the .php and .js files to be tracked. So I then ran `git add *.php *.js`, that didn't work.. so I just tried `git add *.php`, which didn't work either. It returns an error saying `error: unknown switch s'`.

However, if I specify a file with `git add lol.php`, it works fine. How can I recursively build my directory structure and track my files with git?

Comment: It appears you have a file with an unfortunate name containing a string like " -s'" or something...

Comment: @Darius Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding using `git add "*.php" "*.js"`

As it currently stands, most probably the [shell globbing](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) is expanding the character `*` in a weird fashion, causing the add command to fail.